# How to raid-mirror existing root partition?

Tags: software-raid

I'd like to mirror my existing root (and only) partition on an SSD to another disk. It should be a sort of RAID-1, just asymmetric<sup>*</sup>. I know there's the option `mdadm --write-behind`, which should do it.

But I have no idea if it is possible with preserving the context of the existing partition. I imagine it like

- create the "slave" partition
- setup the RAID telling it that the slave partition is not initialized
- let it initialize it by cloning the master partition

but I'm probably too optimistic, aren't I?

---

<sup>* All reads should access the first disk and writes should be considered finished when the first disk is written.</sup>

Comment: A friend of my friend recently nuked all his data by running `mdadm --create` while trying to achieve the same thing. I don't know how to do it correctly but that's not the way.

Comment: @stribika: You can run `mdadm --create` on an existing disk as long as you choose a superblock version that goes to the end of the disk, and shrink the filesystem accordingly.

Comment: @Gilles: I think he didn't do the degraded trick just added both disks to the array and hoped it would sync the right way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create an mdraid RAID-1 array starting with an existing partition. First, you need to make room for the mdadm superblock, which means you need to shrink your filesystem a little.

At the moment, the normal superblock format is [0.9](https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/RAID_superblock_formats#The_version-0.90_Superblock_Format). Its location is between 128kB and 60kB from the end of the partition, it is 4kB long, and it starts on an address that is a multible of 64kB. So shrink your filesystem by 128kB, or more precisely to ((device_size mod 64kB) - 1) * 64kB.

If you want more than 2TB per stripe, you need the [1.0 superblock format](https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/RAID_superblock_formats#The_version-1_superblock_format_on-disk_layout), which isn't supported out-of-the-box by all distributions yet. The 1.0 superblock is at the end of the device, which I understand to mean that you only need to shrink your filesystem by 8kB.

Now that you've shrunk the filesystem, you can create the array. First create a degraded array with just the existing data. Make sure the filesystem isn't mounted at this point. For your use case the write-intent bitmap must be on a separate partition. Use `-e 1.0` to use the newer version-1 superblock format.

```
mdadm --create /dev/md0 -e 0.9 -l 1 -n 2 \
      --write-behind=256 --bitmap=/path/to/bitmap /dev/sda1 missing
```

Now you can mount the filesystem in `/dev/md0`. Add the second disk at your leasure. The data will be copied to the new drive in the background.

```
mdadm --add /dev/md0 --write-mostly /dev/sdb1
```

<sub>*I've created a mirrored array like this, but without write-behind mode. I don't think write-behind mode would invalidate the procedure.*</sub>

Comment: Great. This would take half the time my method takes.

Comment: Can I remove the write-intent later?

Comment: @Lionel: I've never tried this myself, but the mdadm manpage documents the following:
* under "For Manage mode", that one can reset --write-mostly with `mdadm --readwrite --re-add /dev/sdb1`
* under `--bitmap`, that one can use `--grow /dev/md0 --bitmap=none`.
BTW, the 1.0 format seems more 'defaultish' by now.

Answer (score 2):

I have an idea. I tested this with small filesystems on loop devices I recommend you do the same before trying it yourself. In this answer /dev/sda is your disk with the important data and /dev/sdb is the new emtpy disk.

```
export DATA_DISK='/dev/sda'
export EMPTY_DISK='/dev/sdb'
```

1. Create a degraded RAID1 array from the **empty disk**. This is important!

   ```
   mdadm --create /dev/md0 --level=1 --raid-devices=2 "${EMPTY_DISK}" missing
   ```
2. Then shrink the filesystem on the disk you want to mirror. (Hopefully it's supported.) This is needed because the RAID arrays have a header and the full filesystem won't fit on the array.
3. Copy the data **to the new degraded array**.

   ```
   dd if="${DATA_DISK}" of=/dev/md0 bs=4k
   ```
4. Add the original disk to the array.

   ```
   mdadm --manage /dev/md0 --add "${DATA_DISK}"
   ```
5. You can watch the synchronization progress.

   ```
   watch 'cat /proc/mdstat'
   ```

Comment: This procedure can be tuned in a few ways (rsync instead of raw copy, settings to choose the syncing bandwidth, and so on). One page describing such techniques which looks good is 
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Convert_a_single_drive_system_to_RAID, though I didn't try that myself.